# Export default not working with specific index.js files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to import a component but I get the following error:

`export 'Window' (reexported as 'default') was not found in './Window' (possible exports: default)`

I'm using a folder and index.js based design (idk if there's a better name for it), so I have a folder named "Window", and it contains the files "Window.js" and "index.js". I'm trying to import it from my WManager.js file (which is in a separate folder).

Window.js looks like this:

```
import './Window.css';

export default function Window () {

    return (
        <div className='Window'>
            window
        </div>
    )
}
```

and index.js looks like this:

```
export { Window as default } from './Window';
```

Meanwhile, my import statement in the file I'm calling it from looks like this:

```
import Window from 'shared/components/Window';
```

I *am* able to successfully import the component if I use the following import:

```
import Window from 'shared/components/Window/Window';
```

but I don't understand why the index.js isn't working. I've used this exact same structure in other places, but for some reason it's not working now.

If it's relevant, the Window file is being accessed through my shared folder, which I am accessing using my src folder as a baseURL in my compiler options. I wouldn't think that this would make any difference, but it seems that this issue only occurs when I try to access items in the shared folder.

Comment: if you use `import {...} from 'location';` it would look for named exports.. You have a default export and no named exports, that is why it is not working..

Comment: This is right, thanks. I fixed it by making ```export { Window as default } from './Window'``` to be ```export { default } from './Window'```

Comment: @WilliamConvertino make your above comment an answer to your question.